# Why are words ending in "-um" and "-us" pluralized to end in "-a" and "-i", respectively?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Where does the practice of using *-a* and *-i* for plural forms of *-um* and *-us*, respectively, come from?

- *Bacteria* vs. *bacterium*
- *Fungi* vs. *fungus*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These words have these plurals because they are loan words from Latin. Words that come from Latin that end in *-um* usually have plurals in *-a*, while those that end in *-us* have plurals in *-i*. This way of forming plurals is normal in Latin, and learned English preserves the native Latin plurals.

Comment: Good observation about the ending, I missed that.

Comment: Key word: "usually." Some words that end in *-us* that are from Latin might have plurals in *-i* or *-us*, depending on the declension.

Comment: *Circus* and *campus* are good examples of Latin words that have regular English plural forms.

Comment: Likewise *status* is of the fourth declension as my boss forcefully reminded me when I once tried to report my *stati* :-)

Comment: And a few words end in -us without coming from Latin (octopus and platypus, for instance).

Comment: octopus and platypus are from greek. Plurals are octopodes and platypodes.

Comment: I am reminded of the classics professor who was mugged by two hoodla ...

Comment: Beware the 3ʳᵈ declension: *corpus > corpora, genus > genera, opus > opera, tempus > tempora*

Comment: @MikeBrown But octopi and platypi are acceptable plural forms.  Basically there's not much point to keeping track of whether a word is Greek or Latin if it ends in something like *us*; you might as well pluralize using *i* since people will make that mistake and then it becomes common usage

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh That doesn’t make sense.  You might as well pluralize *corpus* > **corpi*, *genus* > **geni*, *opus* > **opi* then — which is nonsense.  What’s *O tempi O morrises* then? A lament concerning morris dancers who can’t keep good time? :)

Comment: Good examples!  I should have put a smiley after my comment; it was meant somewhat tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh, if you’re going to argue that keeping track of etymologies and original plurals is persnickety and somewhat pointless (which is a valid argument), at least argue for creating _regular_ plurals for them, rather than just making up strange ones. ‘Octopuses’ and ‘platypuses’ are both infinitely preferable to ‘octopi’ and ‘platypi’, the mere typing of which just caused my fingers to go into apoplectic spasms of etymological epilepsy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "...just making up strange ones"?  I didn't make it up though, as I think you are well aware.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh, no, I meant rather than arguing for the practice of making up these horrible hybrid plurals, not making them up yourself. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, I wasn't arguing for that per se.  I was arguing for ambivalence.

Answer (score 3):

It comes from people who still remember that a word is a loan word and the lending language was inflected.  Often people attempting to inflect the way Latin does do a poor job of it, so outside of the most common Latinisms, it would be better style to use ordinary plurals.

Answer (score 1):

These words are loan words from Latin. The plurals associated with words ending in -um or -us are not dictated by practice, but by precise, Latin, rules.

In Latin - which is an inflected language - there are 5 declensions. Nouns are distributed among declensions and follow declension-specific rules.

So, a noun belonging to the second declension and ending in -us (such as *lupus*), will have *lupi* as plural, while one belonging to the same declension and ending in -um will have an -a plural (*bellum* -> *bella*).

Note that in Latin nouns have a gender, so *lupus* is male, while *bellum* is neuter.

A noun belonging to the fourth declension such as *spiritus* (male) will have *spiritus* as plural.

Comment: I wouldn't say the plurals are dictated by precise rules.  On the contrary, I would say they are dictated by inconsistently applied rules that were, at some stage, informed by Latin pluralization. We have Latin words that have regular English plurals (*campus* pluralizes as *campuses*), Latinesque plurals for words people think are Latin that aren't, like *octopus-octopi* (*octopus* is Greek), words that were originally plural in Latin that are now mass nouns (*data*), and words where the Latin plural form is often used for singular and plural (*alumni*).

Comment: @Kosmonaut -- just my opinion, but anyone who uses "alumni" as a singular should be shot into space...

Comment: The *precise rules* statement referred to the Latin plurals, not to the English ones :)

Comment: @Malvolio If you want to extend that to Italian, anyone who uses *panini* as a singular word should be shot.

Comment: people say "a panini"?  OK, I've never heard that but yes, anyone saying it will be condemned to live on Wonder Bread and yellow mustard for the rest of his life.  How do people feel about 'an agenda'?

Comment: @Malvolio *Alumni* is a perfectly fine singular form — in the genitive, that is.  It means *alumnus’s*.

Comment: @tchrist: if we were speaking Latin, which we aren't, so it's *not* a perfectly fine form in the singular.

Comment: @RobertoAloi, even in Latin, the rules are far from precise—they are, in fact, full of inconsistencies and irregularities. And as Kosmonaut said, there are plenty of words in English that are taken directly from Latin, but are not declined as in Latin. You even mentioned one of them in your answer: ‘lupus’, whose plural, though rare, is ‘lupuses’.

Comment: I had been wondering why *strata* is the plural form of *stratum*, as well as where the word originated, and I found the answer(s) here. Its etymology in Dictionary.com would be from Latin *strāta*. See also these pages: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441504/why-is-genera-the-plural-form-of-genus; https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536822/why-is-stigmata-a-plural-of-stigma