# Why is "genera" the plural form of "genus"?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

I'm not familiar with irregular Latin pluralization, so this may be a simple question with a simple answer. Other Latin words ending in "us" don't pluralize to "era"

Comment: What Is the Plural of Genus? https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-plural-of-genus-1857287

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension. *Genus* is a third-declension neuter noun. Don't think of the *-era* as being the plural of *-us*; rather, think of *gener-* as being its own stem used in certain forms of *genus*. (This is not considered irregular in Latin, even if it seems irregular by English standards.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's technically about Latin, not about English, even though English has borrowed these words.  (There is a Latin SE).

Comment: It's just as much a question about English as is the question of why the plural of "child" is "children". The fact that the answer re "genus" involves Latin, or even that the OP anticipated that, is beside the point.

Comment: . . . . . and diseases of Venus are "venerial diseases". And some saints are accorded "veneration".

Comment: This is a question about Latin, not English.

Comment: The word "genus" has been used in English for the best part of 500 years: *1551   T. Wilson Rule of Reason sig. Bv   Genus is a general word, the which is spoken of many that differ in their kind... Or els thus. Genus, is a general worde, vnder the whiche diuers kindes or sortes of things are comprehended.* It may be time to accept it into English. ++ I would use **genuses** unless I were willing to decline it (singular and plural) in the ablative, vocative, and other cases.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genus) says that the plural, as used in English, can be either _genuses_ or _genera_. _Genuses_ is listed as the alternative plural to _genera_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English has borrowed many words from Latin and often the plural in the original gets carried along, instead of just using the English plural.

- usually words ending in -us (second declension) have a plural in -i, and that is the most common 'true-to-latin' plural in English is: eg alumnus -> alumni (though pronounced English style: uh-LUM-nigh, different from the more Latin ah-LUM-knee).
- but the plural, *in Latin*, for some Latin neuter nouns ending in -us is different because they fall under the third declension, with its own set of endings. -a is the nominative plural ending for third declension neuters), and under which the final -s undergoes the Latin plural sound change called [rhoticization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism_(sound_change)#Latin) changing s to r: opus -> opera, which means work -> works, an opera is originally a collection of pieces. This is the answer to why the -Latin- plural has 'r' instead of 's', because it was in the transition in Proto-Italic [between Old and Classical Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Italic_language#Post-Italic_developments) when the rhotacization occurred.

**Opus/opera, genus/genera, corpus/corpora** are the relatively more common examples, the others are much rarer (viscus/viscera).

Comment: It isn't an *irregular* plural, it's just different from the plural for second-declension -us nouns. For third-declension nouns, stem+<a> is the regular plural for neuter nouns, including the ones ending in -us. The stem itself, it's true, needs to be learned verb by verb for the third declension, though there are patterns. Rex/reg-, nox/noct-, mens/ment-, ops/op-, opus/oper-, etc. (I know you know these details, but I'm presenting them for others to explain my point about this being a regular construction.)

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm Frankly, anything to me that's not first or second declension is irregular. What a mess. You want me to learn five cases, singular and plural, _and_ for five different declensions? What, locative too? _And_ neuter_ forms? Shut the front porta.

Comment: or portam. Whatevs

Comment: Your complaint about the complexity of Latin is duly noted. :-) Do yourself a favor and avoid Icelandic. :-D The back of my Icelandic grammar presents 74 different noun paradigms, and that's *before* getting into irregular nouns.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm [Toki Pona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toki_Pona) for the win.

Comment: You may also want to check out this page: https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/wc/a-strange-plural-phenomena/

Comment: @EricVelazquez I was about to get really upset: "That singular sounds really wro... Oh... I see what you did there"

Comment: You're forgotten all the fourth declension nouns like nominative singular *manŭs, frūctŭs, apparatŭs, prospectŭs*, whose nominative plurals and genitive singulars change the short *ŭ* to long *ū* yielding *manūs, frūctūs, apparatūs, prospectūs* respectively.

Comment: Also, you have to learn six cases, not five, because the second declension has a different vocative, so *Brūtus* becomes *Hey Brūte!* The reason this matters is because adjectives in the second declension also change "us" > "e" when they're in the vocative.